# bringing Process Builder into trigger

Tags: apex, after-trigger

I am trying to bring a process builder into a trigger and am having some trouble getting my apex class to know when a field changes. I've tried to research this and haven't been able to come up with anything. Once I get the "is changed" figured out I need to be able to populate Leads and Opportunities the values from my Campaign. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm getting an error at the line 
`if(oldObj.get(Schema.Required_Documents__c) != s.get(Schema.Required_Documents__c))` that the variable doesn't exist.

here is my code:

```
trigger TriggerCampaignReqDocs on Campaign (after update) {
    TriggerCampaignReqDocsUtil.collectAllowedCampaignTypes();
}
```

apex class:

```
public class TriggerCampaignReqDocsUtil {    
    //Constructor
    public void TriggerCampaignReqDocsUtil(){
    }

    public static void collectAllowedCampaignTypes(){
    Set<Id> leadsToUpdate = new SET<Id>();
    Set<Id> oppsToUpdate = new SET<Id>();
        //get a list of all allowable Campaign types.
        List<String> allowedCampaignTypes = new List<String>{
           'Enablement',
           'New Vendor - Temporary',
           'New Vendor - Funded Conversion',
           'Retailer Sponsored – Standard',
           'Retailer Sponsored – Low Volume',
           'Churn',
           'Existing Vendor Onboarding'
        };
        //get a list of all allowable Lead Status.
        List<String> allowedLeadStatus = new List<String>{
            'Open',
            'In Progress',
            'Escalation',
            'Escalation Resolution',
            'On Hold'
        };
        //get a list of all allowable Opp Stage Names relevant.
        List<String> allowedOppStatus = new List<String>{
              'Qualification',
              'Discovery',
              'Proof',
              'Negotiation'
            };   
        //get the related open Opps
        List<Opportunity> lstOpps = [Select id, StageName, Required_Documents__c, Order_Management_Model__c, DocumentsOptional__c, CampaignId, 
                                         Exclude_Campaign_Doc_Sync_Oppty__c
                                         from Opportunity where CampaignId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() AND StageName IN :allowedOppStatus AND 
                                         Exclude_Campaign_Doc_Sync_Oppty__c = False];

        List<Lead> lstLeads = [Select id, Primary_Campaign_Source_Lead__c, Required_Documents__c, Order_Management_Model__c, DocumentsOptional__c, Status, Exclude_Campaign_Doc_Sync_Lead__c
                                   from Lead WHERE Primary_Campaign_Source_Lead__c IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() AND Campaign_Type__c IN :allowedCampaignTypes 
                                   AND Status IN :allowedLeadStatus AND Exclude_Campaign_Doc_Sync_Lead__c = False];

        for (sObject s : Trigger.new){
            sObject oldObj = Trigger.oldMap.get(s.Id);
            if(lstOpps.size() > 0){ 
                system.debug('!!! I have a list of Opps: ' +lstOpps);
                if(oldObj.get(Schema.Required_Documents__c) != s.get(Schema.Required_Documents__c)){
                system.debug('!!! I know the difference of Required Docs! ');
                }
                /*if(s.Documents_required__c != trigger.oldMap.get(s.Id).Documents_Required__c){
                s.Required_Documents__c = lstOpps.Required_Documents__c;
                s.Order_Management_Model__c = lstOpps.Order_Management_Model__c;
                s.DocumentsOptional__c = lstOpps.DocumentsOptional__c;                    
                }*/
                //oppsToUpdate.add(s.Required_Documents__c);
                //oppsToUpdate.add(s.DocumentsOptional__c);
                //oppsToUpdate.add(s.Order_Management_Model__c);
                //update oppsToUpdate;
                    if(lstLeads.size() > 0){
                        system.debug('!!! I have a list of Leads: ' +lstLeads);
                        //s.Required_Documents__c = lstLeads.Required_Documents__c;
                        //s.Order_Management_Model__c = lstLeads.Order_Management_Model__c;
                        //s.DocumentsOptional__c = lstLeads.DocumentsOptional__c;
                }//end if lstLeads
           }//end if lstOpps
        }//end for sobject s
    }//end collectAllowedCampaignTypes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing I think is your issue is `Schema.Required_Documents__c`

This seems like an incomplete way of getting a field token, which would be something like `Schema.Account.My_Custom_Field__c` (which you can use with the `get()` method of the SObject class).

While using the field token provides some safety (it'll cause Salesforce to prevent someone from deleting the field while it's still in use), I think it's probably overkill for your situation.

I might suggest doing some type casting so you can just use the normal dot-notation, since it appears that you're only working with a single object here (Campaign). That'd look something like this

```
// We can cast trigger context variables when they're being used outside of a trigger
//   so that we can continue to use dot-notation to access fields
for (Campaign camp :(List<Campaign>)Trigger.new){

    // Same thing for individual records
    Campaign oldCamp = (Campaign)Trigger.oldMap.get(s.Id);
    if(lstOpps.size() > 0){ 
        if(oldcamp.Required_Documents__c != camp.Required_Documents__c){
            system.debug('!!! I know the difference of Required Docs! ');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great point and tip! however, I'm still getting an error:
Variable does not exist: Required_Documents__c

Comment: is the field not available because I'm using a List? would I need to use either a set or Map to be able to use the field (this field is a multi-select picklist field..)

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the actual name of the field.. once corrected, it worked!

Thank you very much Derek!!